# How can I add vue in mvc html tag?

Tags: c#, .net, vue.js, model-view-controller, razor

I'm having a problem when adding vue inside mvc tag like shown below;

```html
@Html.CheckBox("isNewlyEnrolled", false)
```

How can I add ref, v-model and v-if inside the element ?

I want it to look like this

```html
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checkboxchecked " ref ="checkbox">
```

or Like this

```html
<input type="checkbox" v-if="!checkboxchecked " ref ="checkbox">
```

```js
var PortalVue = new Vue({
    data: function() {
        return {
            checkboxchecked : false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkboxchecked_method : function () {
            alert("a")
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the third parameter of checkbox to add attributes. Underscores get converted into dashes in Razor. You also need the @ for reserved keywords, like ref.

```
@Html.CheckBox("isNewlyEnrolled", false, new { @v_model = "checkboxchecked", @ref = "checkbox" })
```

Comment: ty2x. I'll try this one.

Comment: what about v-on:click ?

Answer (score 0):

you have **conflicting names**
change the method name and then try again
[Conflicting method and data names.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/565)